# How to return to the root of a navigation graph?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

How can I return to the root Fragment using the `NavController`?
I tried

```
navController.popBackStack(navController.graph.startDestination, false)
```

but it did not work. This did work:

```
navController.navigate(navController.graph.startDestination, false)
navController.popBackStack(0, false)
```

but I'm wondering if this is a proper way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 18):

you can use this method, but your arguments are wrong,
The first argument is the ID of destination, for back to root you have to use:

```
findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.Dashboard, false)
```

Where Dash is the ID of view on your navigation graph